# Is there any mini game available for the today section in notification center yosemite?

Tags: macos

Is there any mini game available for the today section in notification center yosemite like that tile game in dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I am aware of.

While the Notification Center is intended to replace the Dashboard in OS X, the purpose of the Notification Center is much more narrow and focused than the Dashboard. The Notification Center is for notifications, small utilities and sharing widgets in contrast to the catch-all hodgepodge the Dashboard was home to.